# Selection with a filter on row number and value

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, subset

I have the following simple data.table "test". I would like to select all rows of row 3 to 8 with X equal to "A":

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
test <- data.table(X=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),Y=rnorm(10),Z=rnorm(10))

test[3:8 & X == "A"] # gives the not desired output:

1: A -0.6264538  1.5117812
2: A  0.1836433  0.3898432
3: A -0.8356286 -0.6212406
4: A  1.5952808 -2.2146999
5: A  0.3295078  1.1249309
Warning message:
  In 3:8 & X == "A" :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

# desired outcome:

3: A -0.8356286 -0.62124058
4: A  1.5952808 -2.21469989
5: A  0.3295078  1.12493092
```

Between row 3:8, I would like to select just the ones with X == "A". How is this possible? Please note that using `test[3:8][X == "A"]` seems not as an option, because I want to do some calculations on these rows which are saved in the original datatable.

Comment: ```test[3:8,][X=="A",]```

Comment: @M-M I was thinking about the same, but I want to perform calcs on the other columns (e.g. Y and Z), which are saved in test. This approach creates a new DT, so the calcs are not saved. Try for instance `test[3:8,][X=="A", Z := Z+3]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here `3:8` is definitely not of the same length as the second expression (`X == "A"`) and more over, we are compare a logical index with a numeric index.  Instead, convert the first expression to logical by using `%in%` on the sequence of rows, then two things happen - 1) lengths become same, 2) Same type

```
test[(seq_len(.N) %in% 3:8) & X == "A"]
#    X          Y          Z
#1: A -0.8356286 -0.6212406
#2: A  1.5952808 -2.2146999
#3: A  0.3295078  1.1249309
```

Comment: thanks I expected it was a one liner. Interesting way to work with `.N`!

Comment: @IceCreamToucan  No problem.  I was about the edit, but there is another solution posted

Answer (score 4):

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
test <- data.table(X=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),Y=rnorm(10),Z=rnorm(10))

test[test[, .I %in% 3:8 & X == "A"], Z := Z+3][]
#>     X          Y           Z
#>  1: A -0.6264538  1.51178117
#>  2: A  0.1836433  0.38984324
#>  3: A -0.8356286  2.37875942
#>  4: A  1.5952808  0.78530011
#>  5: A  0.3295078  4.12493092
#>  6: B -0.8204684 -0.04493361
#>  7: B  0.4874291 -0.01619026
#>  8: B  0.7383247  0.94383621
#>  9: B  0.5757814  0.82122120
#> 10: B -0.3053884  0.59390132
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @M-M. I accepted akrun's answer who was a little bit faster

Comment: @Talik3233 no worries, it was just yesterday that akrun and I were talking about them being an adversary to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select rows from certain index(3:8) and then filter out a variable with certain value(here X == 'A'), 
you can try out with `dplyr package':

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
test <- data.table(X=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),Y=rnorm(10),Z=rnorm(10))

test %>% slice(3:8) %>% filter(X == 'A')
```

Comment: Fyi, OP noted in a comment that they want to update/mutate those rows. (Your post is still a valid answer to the question posted, though.)